# How to store current date in a record as a Day type only?

Tags: date, haskell, record

How can I store in a record the current date as a `Day` type? Is this the correct way of doing it? I want to do this to be able to manipulate dates in the application but also to store them in a database using Opaleye or Esqueleto.

I have this:

```
import Data.Time
import Data.Time.Format

data User = User
  { userId    :: Int
  , name      :: Text
  , loginDate :: Day
  } deriving (Eq, Show)


currentDay :: Day
currentDay = utctDay <$> getCurrentTime ???

users :: [User]
users = [ User 1 "A" currentDay
        , User 2 "B" currentDay
        ]
```

But the type of `currentDay` is `IO Day`. How can I get it as `Day` only? I am guessing that is not possible without breaking type safety but I am not sure.

I could change the type of `loginDate` to `IO Day` but then I wouldn't be able to derive `Eq` and `Show` and thus be unable to use `deriveJSON` while using Servant. If I change the type of `currentDay` to `IO Day` and `users` to `IO [User]` then I cannot use Servant types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentDay` (as well as `getCurrentTime`) is an IO-action. You have to execute it in the IO-monad to retrieve the current day.

You code should look like:

```
currentDay :: IO Day
currentDay = utctDay <$> getCurrentTime

createUsers :: IO [User]
createUsers = do
  today <- currentDay
  return [ User 1 "A" today, User 2 "B" today ]
```

Comment: But I can't use the IO monad with servant, can I?

Comment: Sure you can. Where do you want to put your code? Usually using `liftIO` is all you need.

Comment: Can you combine two endpoints in which one is in the IO monad (`IO [User]`) and the other isn't (`[Friend]`) ?

Comment: `[Friend]` is a pure value so I'm sure you can, but I'm exactly sure of what context you're referring to, so I don't know how to show you how to do it. Can you come up with a short example of what you're trying to do? And it would be appropriate to post it as a new question.